# How to Authorize VS Code to Dev Org with SSO/Okta

Tags: single-sign-on, vs-code, okta

I am looking to authorize my VS Code to an org that utilizes SSO/Okta.  How can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After calling the authorize an org command, you'll be in Salesforce. From there, click on the "Use a custom domain" link, and enter your org's domain. Assuming SSO is configured correctly, Salesforce will automatically redirect you to the SSO server, and when it sends the SAML message back to Salesforce, and access is granted to the app, it will in turn send an access token back to VS Code.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox!